# VC++ 2015 text visualizer for UTF8?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I'm using std::string. In 'Autos' and 'Locals' debug window, the UTF8 string shows garble characters.

Is there a way to show readable UTF8?

Comment: I cannot replicate your problem, but does this help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/format-specifiers-in-cpp

Comment: @VuVirt I use 'text,s8', it still doesn't display UTF8. And the size field displays '<Error reading characters of string.>'.

Comment: Try something else

Comment: Like "sb" or "su" for instance

Comment: 'sb' doesn't change anything similar to 's8', while 'su' gave me more garbled text.

Comment: Have you changed your Windows' language settings lately? Other than that, it might be a problem with VS installation. You might try to re-install VS.